# Incorrect authentication with wrong password

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working on a form which is like a user login form but without default django's default authorisation. so it takes parameters and check that whether password entered is correct or not .

```
def clean(self):
    form_data=self.cleaned_data
    LoginUsername=form_data['Username']
    LoginPassword=form_data['Password']
    if DiaryUser.objects.filter(Username=LoginUsername):
        UserCredentials=DiaryUser.objects.filter(Username='LoginUsername')
        for UserCredential in UserCredentials:
            if UserCredential.Password !=LoginPassword:
                raise ValidationError("The Password is not correct ")
    else:
        self._errors["Username"]="The User Credentials entered is not present in our database"
        del form_data['Username']
    return form_data
```

But when User enters wrong password it keeps on redirecting to success page. what is wrong with above code snippet.

Comment: Don't write your authentication code yourself, use django's `auth` package instead. Whatever you may think, it will save you a LOT of time and pain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Update the code like this using [exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

```
if not DiaryUser.objects.filter(Username=LoginUsername, Password=LoginPassword).exists():  # FYI Keeping plain passwords in DB is not safe and ofcourse not recommended.
     raise ValidationError("The Password is not correct ")
```

Comment: but after implementing the solution , the page is taking time to load

Answer (score 0):

thanks @ruddra, but it makes my page considerably but following snippet works for me

```
    form_data=self.cleaned_data
    LoginUsername=form_data['Username']
    LoginPassword=form_data['Password']
    if DiaryUser.objects.filter(Username=LoginUsername,Password=LoginPassword).exists():
        pass
    else:
        self._errors["Username"]="The User Credentials entered is not present in our database"
        return form_data
```

thanks again ruddra